# flatMapIterable is not emitting object in list

Tags: java-8, rx-java, rx-java2, flatmap

Thanks in advance for help.

I have a scenario, where I am taking an input of order details(includes order object and list of orderItem object).

My aim is to first create an order and then use the orderId generated to create orderItems.

below is the code written to do the above mentioned task.

orderCreate object

```
public class OrderCreate {

    @JsonProperty("order")
    Order order;

    @JsonProperty("orderItem")
    List<OrderItem> orderItem;
}
```

service code

```
public Observable<ResponseEntity<OrderCreate>> createOrder(OrderCreate orderCreate) {

    Observable<ResponseEntity<OrderCreate>> order = 
    Observable.just(orderCreateDao.createOrder(orderCreate))
    .<ResponseEntity<OrderCreate>> flatMap((ord) -> {
        System.out.println("step1");
        Observable.just(ord.getBody().getOrderItem())
        .flatMapIterable(oisd -> oisd)
        .flatMap(oi -> {
            System.out.println("step2");
            oi.setOrderId(ord.getBody().getOrder().getOrderId());
            ResponseEntity<String> ordItemIs = orderCreateDao.createOrderItem(oi);
            return Observable.just(ordItemIs);
        });
        System.out.println("step3");
        return Observable.just(ord);
    });
    return order;
}
```

in the above code step1 and step3 are executing but not step2.

Comment: The `getOrderItem` could be returning an empty iterable.

Comment: I checked, getOrderItem is returning list of orderItem

Comment: You did not subscribe to that Observable you setup after step1.